# os.startfile() not opening .py file

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to open a .py file with os and it seems to open a browser not the assigned, file this is the code.

```
if log == l_p:
    print("Opening Home Page...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.startfile("home.py")
    break
```

Comment: you want to open with what ? An application that display the text or read the content into a string ?

Comment: its supposed to open into another terminal

Comment: if you want to "call python code form python code" that is absolutly not the way to do : you import code from another file and call it, you stay fully into python not other process to run it. So is that only a test to understand some stuff and not your actual way to call python from multiple files ?

Comment: os.startfile() is Windows only (but you probably knew that). What will happen is that Windows will pass (in your case) 'home.py' to whatever application is associated with the '.py' extension. You'll find the documentation illuminating:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html